# Issues printing whilst using getline()

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printf

I'm just having a bit of difficulty with a print. Basically, I have code and I'm assigning values to `bestmatch[]`, which is defined as being of type `line_t` (see struct at bottom).

As you can see, I am storing values for `bestmatch[].score (double)`, `bestmatch[].index (int)` and `bestmatch[].buf (string)`. When I print them, show in second code block below, `bestmatch[i].index` and `bestmatch[i].score` print correctly; however, `bestmatch[i].buf` does not print at all.

Just to confuse matters more (for myself at least), if I print `bestmatch[i].buf` at the end of scorecmp (first code block), it prints fine. I've got my call to scorecmp down the very bottom for reference.

**Why is it that it is printing index and score fine, but not buf? Or even more, how can I fix this behaviour?**

Thank you for your help! Please let me know if you need any additional information

The print, appearing in main, is as follows (for reference, TOP_SCORING_MAX is the number of elements in bestmatch[]):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i<TOP_SCORING_MAX; i++) {
    if (bestmatch[i].score != -1) {
        printf("line\t%d, score = %6.3f and string is %s \n", 
            bestmatch[i].index,bestmatch[i].score, bestmatch[i].buf);
    }
}
```

And in case you would like the struct:

```
typedef struct line_t {
  char* buf;
  int lineLength;   
  int wordCount;
  int index;
  double score;
} line_t;
```

This is my call to scorecmp:

```
scorecmp(linePtr, bestmatch);
```

Comment: You must show how you initialize the data, what kind of strings are the `buf` pointers pointing at?

Comment: @unwind buf is a single line of an input text file from stdin. I get it using: getline(&line.buf, &maxSz, stdin))

Comment: @KittiCat That's your problem right there, unless you also use `malloc()` to set `buf` to a valid memory area to hold the string, of course. As I said, show more code.

Comment: @unwind What code do you need that I've forgotten to put, sorry?

Comment: "This is my call to `scorecmp`"??? Not it's not, it's your declaration of `scorecmp`!!!

Comment: @barakmanos excuse me for copying the wrong code. i'll update now.

Comment: @KittiCat: No problem , though it doesn't really help answering your question (at least until we know the contents of each of the arguments that you are passing to this function).

Comment: @barakmanos is there anything else I can add to assist? Okay, well there obviously is something. What have I left out?

Comment: @KittiCat Show the entire loop where you input text lines from stdin and store them in an array of your structure.

Comment: @KittiCat: The **contents** of `linePtr` and `bestmatch`.

Comment: @barakmanos I've added the rest of the code for scorecmp (that has all of bestmatch I believe) and at the bottom I have added the loop that takes inputs from stdin. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the content of the strings, not just the pointers, because they seem to be destroyed, freed, or mutilated before you print them:

```
 bestmatch[j].buf = strdup(linePtr->buf);
```

Don't forget to free the copied string at the end.

Comment: Or you could use malloc + memcpy and make the code portable.

Comment: Ohh!! I think I understand what's happening now. Would I be able to use strcpy to do this?

Comment: This really depends on the arguments that function `scorecmp` is called with. Since OP has not specified that information, your answer is an educated guess (most likely a correct one, nevertheless, still a guess).

Comment: @KittiCat: Not until you specify the contents of each of the arguments that you are passing to function `scorecmp`.

Comment: @barakmanos I just tried using strdup, but got a bus error. It is almost definitely my implementation though, but I'll let you read through above edit before discussing further (=

Answer (score 0):

The `getline` function is the preferred method for reading lines of text from a stream.

The other standard functions, such as `gets`, `fgets` and `scanf`, are a little too unreliable.

The `getline` function reads an entire line from a stream, up to and including the next newline character.

This function takes three parameters:

1. A pointer to a block of memory allocated with `malloc` or `calloc`. This parameter is of type `char**`, and it will contain the line read by `getline` when the function returns.
2. A pointer to a variable of type `size_t`. This parameter specifies the size in bytes of the block of memory pointed to by the first parameter.
3. The stream from which to read the line.

The first parameter - a pointer to the block of memory allocated with `malloc` or `calloc` - is merely a suggestion. Function `getline` will automatically enlarge the block of memory as needed via `realloc`, so there is never a shortage of space - one reason why this function is so safe. Not only that, but it will also tell you the new size of the block, by updating the value returned in the second parameter.

---

That being said, **every time** you call function `getline`, you first need to:

- Set `maxSz` to a reasonable size.
- Set `line.buf = malloc(maxSz)`.

Set the value of `maxSz` not too large, in order to reduce the amount of redundant memory used.

Set the value of `maxSz` not too small, in order to reduce the number of times `getline` calls `realloc`.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but how would this fix the issue? I don't fully understand, that's all

Comment: @KittiCat: First of all, you need to try and understand this answer, if you want to understand the problem that you're dealing with. Second, if you just want a solution, then it is given to you at the bottom of the answer. Again, I strongly recommend that you try to understand what the problem is (by reading the answer above).

Comment: @KittiCat: I also recommend that you change the title of your question to "A problem with function getline" or something similar, because that's where your problem is. If you do that, then you might get a few more answers to your question (thus possibly making it easier for to understand).

Comment: I've been printing line.buf in other places and it seems to print fine. Why wouldn't it work in this case?

Comment: @KittiCat: I don't know what you did "in other places", but most likely it is a matter of chance. If you do not properly set `line.buf` to point to a block of memory allocated with `malloc` or `calloc`, then function `getline` performs undefined behavior, meaning that anything can happen (it might work and it might not).

Comment: Oh okay. Sure, so when I place that (the realloc solution) code in, do I put it just within my while loop (the one that calls getline)?

Comment: Okay, so I tried implementing that solution. Unfortunately, just within my while loop I printf("%s",line.buf), and that stops working - and the bit that was originally not printing continues to not print

Comment: You say, if I want to print using %s: does this mean there is another way to print this?

Comment: @KittiCat: I meant to say that `printf("%s",x)` expects to find an array of characters that end with a 0 character, at the memory address pointed by `x`.

Comment: Because line.buf is seemingly working fine, despite apparent flaws, would I be able to instead null terminate bestmatch[j].buf?